# fopen() is unable to open file

Tags: c, string, file, fopen

I am trying to open a file and read the contents of it. **But, I am currently stuck on just trying to open it.**

**Here is my code:**

```
void read_contents(char* file_path)
{
    printf("\nOriginal path: %s\n", file_path);

    // Trying to prefix the path with "." to indicate that the path is relative.
    char prefix[1024] = ".";
    
    strcat(prefix, file_path);

    // Printing to make sure that prefix contains correct path.
    printf("\nPath after concatenating: %s\n", prefix);

    FILE* file = fopen(prefix, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
       perror("Error");
    
       // Close the file and stop the function.
       fclose(file);
       return;
    }


    // Code to read the file...
    // ...
    // Code to read the file...


    fclose(file);
}
```

**Here is the output: (Keep in mind that it does not even reach the reading part)**

```
Original path: /input_files/file_1.txt

Path after concatenating: ./input_files/file_1.txt

Error: no such file or directory
```

**Here is my directory structure:**

```
root:

executable
input_files (this is a folder)
  file_1.txt
```

The executable is located at the same level as the folder named "input_files". Inside the input_files is where the text file is located.

**Additional things:**

1. I am running the correct executable from the terminal.
2. The path is correct when passing to the function.
3. The structure and names of my folders and files are correct.
4. The permissions are correct for accessing and reading files.
5. The "." is added to the beginning of the string correctly.

With all this I still get an error saying **no such file or directory**. Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: If you're trying to figure out why you're files don't seem to be found then always print out the current working directory as part of your debugging effort.

Comment: Why did you add the dot at the front? That completely changes the meaning of the path.

Comment: I added the "." to the beginning of the string, because I tried to accomplish the same thing without it and I kept getting an error. 

After some research I found that apparently if you want to refer to the current directory you need to say "./" (at least under Linux). That is why I decided to do that. Why? Is it wrong? If so, then please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Looks like your actual directories and files have an additional `__` prefixed to them.  If that is part of the name, you'll need to include it in the path strings.

Comment: I apologize for that, I used the underscores as a means to better demonstrate the structure like a tree. Please ignore the beginning underscores. I removed them just in case.

Comment: If `fopen()` failed you don't want to `fclose()` it.  Paths starting with `/` is an absolute path, everything else is relative.  The path ./x` is the same as just `x`.

Comment: Put your program to one side. In the same terminal, type `cat ./input_files/file_1.txt`. What do you observe?

Comment: Given your setup, the program should work if executed by "./executable". If you launch it with, say, "../executable" then it will not work.

Comment: This is truly frustrating, I completely and fully understand what you are all suggesting and appreciate it, but for some reason it is just acting weird.

I even tried the suggestion for this command: cat ./input_files/file_1.txt

When I execute this command from the terminal from the exact location of my executable it actually gives me valid results:

10
20
30

At this point I am speechless. If I give the exact same thing to my program, then fopen() says it cannot find file.

Comment: I have checked the path, executable location, file structure, file names, folder names, and debug statements such as getcwd(), printf, etc over and over again (27 times) now and for the love of me I don't see any difference. And yet the command works but fopen() does not. 

I am loosing my brain cells at this point.

Comment: just guessing, there's algo misinterpreted. Idk, maybe you call it with some extra whitespaces at the end of a string or with '\r', or something like that

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading all possible and common solutions in this kind of cases, which didn't work in your case, my only guess can be the malformed C-string passed to function, which can be treated as correct at a first glance.
I managed to reproduce the **similar** problem at my site only having malformed C-string pointer passed to *read_contents* function.

**The main idea.**
Let's say you have some statically initialized array in your main function which length is more than that of path of file. In my reproduced case I took byte array with 100 bytes in it.

```
char path2[100] = {0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x02};
```

also I have

```
char path[] = "/file.txt" // strlen on this will result in 10 (includes \0)
```

After I copy the 9 bytes of memory to path2 buffer from path (excluding \0)

```
memcpy(path2, path, 9);
```

Note that I already prepared the replacement for *null-terminator* byte in **path2** - `0x02` byte (it may be any garbage value)
After copying the memory from correct buffer to **path2** buffer. The resulting string is also correct and if we print it out we see exactly the same string, **but**, the last byte before **null-terminator** is 0x02 and not the last symbol from initial path.
To be precise the **path2** buffer will look like this after memcpy.

```
2F 66 69 6C 65 2E 74 78 74 02 00 .... 00
/  f  i  l  e  .  t  x  t     \0
```

instead of correct

```
2F 66 69 6C 65 2E 74 78 74 00 .... 00
/  f  i  l  e  .  t  x  t  \0
```

When try to print out this string you won't even see empty char, as if spare byte does not exist, but for system it matters C:

When invoking your provided function I get this kind of output

```
artyom@artyom:~/workspace/fopenfail$ ./a.out 
Strlen /file.txt = 10
Original path: /file.txt

Path after concatenating: ./file.txt
Error: No such file or directory


artyom@artyom:~/workspace/fopenfail$ ls
a.out  file.txt  main.c
artyom@artyom:~/workspace/fopenfail$
```

Here is the code I used as possible example

```
void read_contents(char* file_path)
{
    printf("\nOriginal path: %s\n", file_path);

    // Trying to prefix the path with "." to indicate that the path is relative.
    char prefix[1024] = ".";

    strcat(prefix, file_path);

    // Printing to make sure that prefix contains correct path.
    printf("\nPath after concatenating: %s\n", prefix);

    FILE* file = fopen(prefix, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
       perror("Error");

       // Close the file and stop the function.
       return;
    }


    // Code to read the file...
    // ...
    // Code to read the file...


    fclose(file);
}

int main()
{
        char path[] = "/file.txt";
        char path2[100] = {0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x02};
        memcpy(path2, path, 9);
        printf("Strlen %s = %d", path2, strlen(path2));

        read_contents(path2);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hope this will serve as hint what is wrong in caller function.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. I completely forgot about this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the error which likely means your current working directory is probably different than expected.  Here is the program you should have provided instead of an incomplete snippet that will print out the current working directory (cwd):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void read_contents(char* file_path) {
    printf("Original path: %s\n", file_path);
    char prefix[strlen(file_path)+2];
    strcpy(prefix, ".");
    strcat(prefix, file_path);
    printf("Path after concatenating: %s\n", prefix);
    FILE* file = fopen(prefix, "r");
    if (!file) {
        perror("Error");
        char cwd[PATH_MAX];
        getcwd(cwd, PATH_MAX);
        printf("cwd: %s\n", cwd);
        return;
    }
    fclose(file);
}

int main(void) {
    read_contents("/input_files/file_1.txt");
    read_contents("/input_files/non-existing.txt");
}
```

and here is an example run:

```
Original path: /input_files/file_1.txt
Path after concatenating: ./input_files/file_1.txt
Original path: /input_files/non-existing.txt
Path after concatenating: ./input_files/non-existing.txt
Error: No such file or directory
cwd: /home/...
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution did not work. I am still getting the same error saying that the file could not be found. I double checked the folder structure and file names and debug statements and the current working directory of my executable and they all seem to be correct.

I don't understand why this is not working.

Comment: If you are getting the same error then you are not using my program as it generates different output.

Comment: It should also be fixing the issue in the accepted answer (before it was posted).